# Using Chinese characters in sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am from china, and I have a question about sqlite, but my English is a bit poor. I'll try to express myself clearly.

Recently, I did something in sqlite using Visual Studio 2005 (VC++) for WinCE development, using an sqlite database. In my table, a field includes some Chinese characters. When i display these, I don't get what I want, because they are all strange characters.

I use the functions' return column value that I want, but I can't.

```
const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
// or
const void *sqlite3_column_text16(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

They said the encodings in sqlite3 is utf8, so you need convert it to unicode. I tried to do this work using a function found on the internet that looks like this:

```
wstring UTF8ToUnicode(const string& strin)
{
    wstring strOut;
    int dwNum = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,strin.c_str(),-1,0,0)
    wchar_t* pBuffer = new wchar_t[dwNum];
    if (!pBuffer){return strOut;}
    memset(pBuffer,0,dwNum*sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,strin.c_str(),-1,pBuffer,dwNum)>=0)
    {
        strOut= pBuffer;
    }
    delete[] pBuffer;
    return strOut;
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the language (C++).

Comment: You might want to explain the line that says _"I use the functions' return column value that I want, but I can't."_... couldn't really tell what point is made there.

Answer (score 4):

"They said the encodings in sqlite3 is utf8"

Whoever said this is wrong.  The encoding used depends on how the database is opened.

"The default encoding for the database will be UTF-8 if sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open_v2() is called and UTF-16 in the native byte order if sqlite3_open16() is used."

http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

However, this hardly matters.  However the data is stored sqlite3_column_text() will always return UTF8 and sqlite3_column_text16() will always return UTF16 in native byte order.  You do not need to write yopur own conversion code.  The only difference is efficiency - it is slightly faster to extract the stored data without a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

After you call const `sqlite3_column_text16`, have you called `sqlite3_column_bytes`? cause if you did, that would change the characters to bytes. Here is my code to get Chinese  it works well.

```
void sqlite3_column_string16(sqlite3_stmt* stmt, int col, std::wstring* str) {
    int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, col);
    const wchar_t* c_str = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(sqlite3_column_text16(stmt, col));
    if (c_str && len > 0)
        str->assign(c_str, len);
    else
        *str = _T("");
}
```